# vba delete all used rows and checkboxes in that row?

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox

I am using the following code to delete all used rows in my spreadsheet.

```
Sub Clear()
With ActiveSheet
    .Rows(13 & ":" & .Rows.Count).Delete
End With
End Sub
```

This works fine and deletes the rows as you might expect. However, in each of my rows I have a checkbox and when the rows are deleted all but 1 checkbox is deleted.

It seems the last checkbox is being pushed up to the row above my delete row range. Please can someone show me a way to make sure all checkboxes are being deleted when I delete all rows?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me, I'm not sure why the last checkbox would be getting pushed up. You could tell it to delete the checkbox by row but I guess you'd have the same problem. Adding this to your code will delete *all* check boxes provided you didn't change their names much after creating them:

```
For Each shape In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    If InStr(Replace(LCase(shape.Name), " ", ""), "checkbox") Then shape.Delete
Next shape
```